# php imagerotate image size grows

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to bring the php gd library into a class structure by myself. Every time I use the imagerotate function the image size gets bigger.

```
<?php
class ImageManipulator
{
    private $image;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            throw new Exception("File not found!");
        }
        $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    }

    public function rotate($angle)
    {
        $this->image = imagerotate($this->image, $angle, 0,false);
        return $this;
    }
   
    public function saveImage($filename)
    {
        imagepng($this->image, $filename);
        return $this;
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }
   
}

// usage
$img = new ImageManipulator("img.png");
$img->rotate(35)->saveImage("img2.png")
->rotate(60)->saveImage("img3.png")
->rotate(90)->saveImage("img4.png");

$img = new ImageManipulator("img.png");
$img->saveImage("img5.png")->saveImage("img6.png")->saveImage("img7.png");
```

my original image size is 800x800. If I just save the picture, the picture size does not change constantly, there is no problem.
[image]

But if I save after rotate it grows.

[image]
[image]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you do not rotate it in a 90/180/270 degree, the rectangular boundary of the image becomes larger. When you rotate it by 45 degree, it should increase from 800 x 800 to 1131 x 1131 (a² + b² = c²)

Comment: The part that seems silly to me is this: I rotated it 45 degrees and it became 1131 x 1131. When I rotate it 45 degrees again, shouldn't it keep its size because it's completed to 90 degrees? Again (a² + b² = c²) it grows in size. In this case, do I need to rescale every 90 degrees and its multiples? And will the picture quality be ruined if I do this? @Uwe

Comment: It happens because, you are rotating probably the "new Image". That means that now the basis is the 1131 x 1131. 

You should work maybe always with the original image and do not the changes depending on the new outcome.

Comment: Your problems don't just end at keeping the image the same size. If you rotate and then resize, your corners will be blacked out. So what you really want is a way to fill the corners as well with data that is not given in the original picture. In other words, what you are trying to do is not trivial.